# SyntaxError (CODEACADEMY)

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing the following problem. Any help would be appreciated. My computer states the following:

> Oops, try again. There was a problem with your syntax. SyntaxError: missing ) after condition.

Can this be located? Or is there some other problem? Any information/thoughts/ideas are appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
// Check if the user is ready to play!
confirm ("I am ready to play!");
var age = prompt ("What's your age");
if (age is less than 13);
{
    console.log ("You can't play this game!");
}
else
{
    console.log ("This game was created for you. Play on!");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using incorrect syntax. Use `if (age < 13)` instead of `if (age is less than 13);`. Note that there is no `;` after the closing `)`